# Is there any website that allows you to choose an algorithm, code it and visualise how it works?

Tags: machine-learning, search, resource-request

I would like to do some practical implementation of a planning algorithm (of course, something a bit simple and easy).

Is there any website where I can pick an algorithm (e.g. A* or hill climbing), code it, and visualize how it works/executes?

The site doesn't necessarily need to be restricted to planning or search algorithms.  For example, in the context of machine learning, I would also like to be able to pick the learning algorithm and model (e.g. linear regression), code it, and visualize how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Not planning, but this is a visual in-browser neural network for your interest:

http://playground.tensorflow.org/

Answer (score 1):

https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html

Great little tool to experiment with various algorithms and compare their efficiencies.